# Matching color of pie charts with another set of data?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I am working with QGIS and as part of the project I would like to make the pie charts give me to sets of information.

I work % of people commuting by bike and I would like the volume of the pie to represent the %age of people commuting in 2015 and the color of the pie to be the growth between 2005 and 2015. So for instance, for Paris, I would like the pie volume to correspond to 1%, while its color would be blue because it grew significantly since 2005. I have multiple cities so I cannot do it by hands.

I looked extensively and could not find anything. Any idea?